# Putting a custom Data Type setting value into a master template

Tags: umbraco

I am using Umbraco 4. I have a custom data type that has a DataEditorSetting like this:

```
    [DataEditorSetting("API Key")]
    public string APIKey { get; set; }
```

This works well as a place to store my API key for the third-party service (previously was a custom property on a document type).

However, I don't know how to get this data into my master template. When it was set up to be a custom property on the document type I had this:

```
<meta name="bingMapsApiKey" 
    id="bingMapsApiKey" 
    content="<umbraco:Item field="bingMapsAPIKey" runat="server" />" 
    />
```

Since switching to use DataEditorSetting the field bingMapsAPIKey no longer exists, naturally.

I need it in the template because there is some JavaScript here that needs the API key to render the map on the page. I can't think of another way to get the value into the JavaScript, so I'm open to different approaches if you know of any.

Answer (score 0):

I've previously used hidden fields to get API Keys into javascript before. You could just add a hidden input and set the value to your API Key with

```
<input type="hidden" id="MyAPIKEy" value="<umbraco:Item field='bingMapsAPIKey' runat='server' />"/>
```

Then just get your API key with some plain javascript or jquery

thanks,

Comment: Since switching to use DataEditorSetting the field bingMapsAPIKey no longer exists. I've updated my question to make that more obvious. I'm looking for some way to get the value of the DataEditorSetting from with a template. Cheers though.